How can you add hotcorners to Ubuntu 24.04?
Ubuntu 24.04 with Wayland has no built-in hotcorner feature. Hot corners are a quick way to trigger actions with the cursor, for example showing the desktop.
Does anyone know an easy and reliable way to add hot corners to Ubuntu 24.04?
There is an extension "Custom Hot Corners" but that requires the Gnome Extension Manager and it is incompatible with gnome-shell 46.
